# Python - calculate die rolls and count doubles

Tags: python, probability, dice

The problem: I need to roll 3 dice. If two (or three) of the dice return the same number, stop. If the 3 dice are all unique (e.g. 2, 4, and 6) then roll again. Perform this either until doubles/triples are rolled, or 7 times, whichever comes first.

Note: I'm a python newb.

Here is what I have so far, but all this does is actually generate the 216 possible combinations:

```
import itertools

all_possible = list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6],3))
input = raw_input()

print all_possible
```

That generates this type of output:

`[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 2), (1, 4, 3), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (1, 5, 2), (1, 5, 3), (1, 5, 4), (1, 5, 6), (1, 6, 2), (1, 6, 3), (1, 6, 4), (1, 6, 5), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 4), (2, 1, 5), (2, 1, 6), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 1), (2, 4, 3), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 1), (2, 5, 3), (2, 5, 4), (2, 5, 6), (2, 6, 1), (2, 6, 3), (2, 6, 4), (2, 6, 5), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 4), (3, 1, 5), (3, 1, 6), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 4), (3, 2, 5), (3, 2, 6), (3, 4, 1), (3, 4, 2), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 6), (3, 5, 1), (3, 5, 2), (3, 5, 4), (3, 5, 6), (3, 6, 1), (3, 6, 2), (3, 6, 4), (3, 6, 5), (4, 1, 2), (4, 1, 3), (4, 1, 5), (4, 1, 6), (4, 2, 1), (4, 2, 3), (4, 2, 5), (4, 2, 6), (4, 3, 1), (4, 3, 2), (4, 3, 5), (4, 3, 6), (4, 5, 1), (4, 5, 2), (4, 5, 3), (4, 5, 6), (4, 6, 1), (4, 6, 2), (4, 6, 3), (4, 6, 5), (5, 1, 2), (5, 1, 3), (5, 1, 4), (5, 1, 6), (5, 2, 1), (5, 2, 3), (5, 2, 4), (5, 2, 6), (5, 3, 1), (5, 3, 2), (5, 3, 4), (5, 3, 6), (5, 4, 1), (5, 4, 2), (5, 4, 3), (5, 4, 6), (5, 6, 1), (5, 6, 2), (5, 6, 3), (5, 6, 4), (6, 1, 2), (6, 1, 3), (6, 1, 4), (6, 1, 5), (6, 2, 1), (6, 2, 3), (6, 2, 4), (6, 2, 5), (6, 3, 1), (6, 3, 2), (6, 3, 4), (6, 3, 5), (6, 4, 1), (6, 4, 2), (6, 4, 3), (6, 4, 5), (6, 5, 1), (6, 5, 2), (6, 5, 3), (6, 5, 4)]`

Which isn't really good either, because it only generates NO doubles or triples--everything, as far as I can see, is just unique combinations only.

----------Update-----------
OK--I took this one and expanded it a little bit by peeling each value from the array and summing them (probably in the least efficient way possible). It works, and if there are multiple sets generated before the break, they all print. What I'm looking to do now is to sum. So:

```
def gen_random_termagants():
for _ in range(7): 
    # instead of three separate variables, we use a list here
    # the nice thing is, that you can freely vary the number of
    # 'parallel' dice rolls this way 
    dice = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(3)]

    # this is more general and will break as soon as there are
    # duplicate (die) values in the list (meaning, break, if not all elements 
    # are different)
    first_die = dice[0]
    second_die = dice[1]
    third_die = dice[2]
    total_term = first_die + second_die + third_die
    print "Total: %s" % total_term
    if len(dice) > len(set(dice)):
        break
```

And here's the output sample:

```
How many tervigons? ::>3
Let's calculate some termagants based on 3 tervigons...
You'll get a minimum of 9 termagants per turn.
You'll get a maximum of 54 termagants per turn.
minimums: 5 turns [45] :: 6 turns [54] :: 7 turns [63]
averages: 5 turns [157] :: 6 turns [189] :: 7 turns [220]
maximums: 5 turns [270] :: 6 turns [324] :: 7 turns [378]
Total: 9
Total: 8
```

So in this example, I want it to return 17 (i.e. 9 + 8).

Comment: Please do not add more questions, just open new ones instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python comes with a [great standard library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/) (as you might already discovered since you are utilizing *itertools*), in which you'll also find a [random](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module.

You could use [random.randint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) to simulate dice rolls. There are multiple ways to solve this. The first code example is somewhat limited, the second is more general.

```
import random

# '_' (underscore) is used for values that are generated, but that you do not
# care about - here we only want to repeat seven times and do not care about
# the actual loop count 
for _ in range(7): 
    # generate three random numbers between [1 and 6] 
    # and store the values in a, b, c respectively (tuple unpacking)
    a, b, c = (random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(3))

    # if one of the conditions holds, break out of the loop early
    if a == b or a == c or b == c or a == b == c:
        break
```

As @Paulo points out, you can use another **more concise** approach to check, whether the `n` elements of a list (or tuple) are all different, that is you put all elements in a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
for _ in range(7): 
    # instead of three separate variables, we use a list here
    # the nice thing is, that you can freely vary the number of
    # 'parallel' dice rolls this way 
    dice = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(3)]

    # this is more general and will break as soon as there are
    # duplicate (die) values in the list (meaning, break, if not all elements 
    # are different)
    if len(dice) > len(set(dice)):
        break
```

Answering your updated question, just use [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
    total = sum(dice)
```

Comment: It's `random.randint(1, 6)`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida, thanks, corrected (overgeneralization from slice semantic ;)

Comment: How about returning a list from the `random.randint` line and then just `if len(rolls) != len(set(rolls))`?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida, I've been thinking about a shorter more general way to express the `if` as well ... - nice variation, I updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: I liked this solution, and expanded on it--see update in original question for a FURTHER question :)

Comment: @MikeEarley, please to not expand too much your original question (since it's short, I answered it anyway - see my updated post). It makes it hard for the answerers and later readers as well. Instead, just a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct output for the permutation of the input, what you are asking for is the Cartesian Product.  See [product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

E.G. This will print the output you are expecting.

```
from itertools import product

d = [ x for x in range(1, 7) ]
for r in product(d, d, d):
    print r
```

Comment: You can also do `product(d, repeat=3)`.

Comment: Also, you can simplify to `d = range(1, 7)`

Comment: @flornquake That would only work for python versions less than 3, right?

Comment: @mr2ert Works in Python 3 too because a range object can be iterated over multiple times.